# PHP PDO Basics! Escaping/Unescaping Special Characters

Tags: php, pdo, escaping, special-characters

Im just starting out with PDO methods and have managed to create a table and insert 10 test records from a .csv file. I checked the table in phpMyAdmin and noticed that fields containing speech marks (in the csv file) were completely enclosed with double quotes like "ORIGINAL CSV VALUE ""WOULD"" BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS" - is this correct or have I done something wrong?

If thats correct, how do I make the output display normally without the extra double quotes?

I hope that makes sense? I have read loads of Q&A's similar to this problem but none of them were explaining what should actually be happening in the DB itself and subsequently how I pull the data back out and display it properly when special characters are involved. I can pull it out and display it - but only with the extra quotes present. Help! Please!

---

Got there in the end. Thanks for the help. You were correct, it was the CSV file that contained the escaped characters so it was working as it should really just not how I wanted it to. Final code below, hope it will help others in the future. It removes the double quotes etc from the CSV data and stores them in the table how they were intended :-)

```
<?php
require_once ('mysql_connect.php');
$databaseFile = fopen('products.csv', 'r');
if ($databaseFile === false) {
    die('Could not open the CSV file!');
}
fgetcsv($databaseFile, 0, "|"); // Removes the CSV header line

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO products (id,category,title,price,shipping,live,height,width,depth) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    while (($csvRow = fgetcsv($databaseFile, 500, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $csvRow[0]);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $csvRow[1]);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $csvRow[2]);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $csvRow[3]);
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $csvRow[4]);
        $stmt->bindValue(6, $csvRow[5]);
        $stmt->bindValue(7, $csvRow[6]);
        $stmt->bindValue(8, $csvRow[7]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

fclose($databaseFile);
$dbConnection = null;
?>
```

Comment: Post code and example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is CSV-style escaping. In CSV, a `"` is *escaped* by writing it twice (`""`). The fact that you see that in your database probably means that the lines and fields from the CSV file were not correctly *un*escaped (transformed) from CSV to regular text before they were inserted.

You can parse (and automatically unescape) CSV strings using the built-in PHP functions [`str_getcsv()`](http://be1.php.net/str_getcsv) (if you already have the CSV file in a string variable) and [`fgetcsv()`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (for when the CSV is still in a file).

See the examples in the linked functions for a better understanding of how to use them.

Once you have the values from the CSV (freshly parsed and unescaped), you can insert them in the database and the `""` should have become a regular `"` again.

Remember that, to insert them in the database, they need database-style escaping again (which is different from CSV style escaping). The easiest way to do this is via PDO prepared statements.

An example:

```
$fileHandle = fopen('someCSVfile.csv', 'rb');
if ($fileHandle === false) {
    die('Could not open the file!');
}

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO testTable(column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

while (($csvRow = fgetcsv($fh) !== false) {
    if (count($csvRow) !== 3) {
        echo 'Encountered a row with a wrong number of fields.';
        continue;
    }

    $stmt->bindValue(1, $csvRow[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $csvRow[1]);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $csvRow[2]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```